# Audio flinger -12 when connecting to bluetooth or disconnecting phone call

Tags: java, android

I'm working in streaming application where Audio track is used with decoder for playing audio.

While connecting phone to Bluetooth or disconnecting phone calls I'm getting this issue and after that audio is not playing.

```
04-24 11:54:36.106: I/Node FSM(14347): Check for lib [/data/data/com.sirius/lib/libomx_aac_custom.so]
04-24 11:54:36.106: I/Node FSM(14347): evt.libs.size() 1, evt.pos=03
04-24 11:54:36.116: E/AudioTrack(14347): **AudioFlinger could not create track, status: -12**
04-24 11:54:36.116: E/AudioTrack-JNI(14347): Error initializing AudioTrack
04-24 11:54:36.116: I/Node FSM(14347): Starting node OMX.PV.aacdec, inst_id=0x7915cd90
04-24 11:54:36.116: I/Node FSM(14347): evt.libs.size() 1, evt.pos=0
04-24 11:54:36.116: I/Node FSM(14347): UNKNOWN->IDLE
04-24 11:54:36.116: I/Node FSM(14347): onStateChange with no action called
04-24 11:54:36.121: I/Node FSM(14347): sending config info 1536 10 49152 9
04-24 11:54:36.121: E/android.media.AudioTrack(14347): Error code -20 when initializing AudioTrack.
04-24 11:54:36.121: I/Node FSM(14347): config info 1536 10 49152 9
```

Audio track specifications:

```
new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                        mConfig.mSampleRate,
                android.media.AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_STEREO,
                        android.media.AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
                        bufferSize, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);

**mConfig.mSampleRate = 44100
bufferSize = 176400 (mConfig.mSampleRate * 4)
```

Previously I had buffersize = 44100 but I was facing audio glitch while playing S5 devices and therefore increased the bufferSize to 176400, not sure this is right way to do.**

Also I'm wondering this change could have caused the Error code -20 issue.
Please let me know what could be the reason for glitch and how to solve it.

I did some analysis and find the below details,

Scenarios:
1.  When app is playing and while connecting to Bluetooth.
2.  On phone call interruption when app is connected to Bluetooth and playing but when not connected to Bluetooth phone call interruption will not cause any issue.

In both scenarios it happens because the Audio track itself is trying to create new Audio track once any of it’s method is called.
1.  “04-27 15:31:12.301: W/AudioTrack(7937): dead IAudioTrack, PCM, creating a new one from start()”
2.  “04-27 15:31:12.304: W/AudioTrack(7937): dead IAudioTrack, PCM, creating a new one from processAudioBuffer()”
3.  “04-27 15:31:12.306: W/AudioTrack(7937): dead IAudioTrack, PCM, creating a new one from obtainBuffer()”

Ex: (In first scenario once the native sentdata method is called to upload the next chunk the issue occurs, in second scenario while pausing the AudioTrack this happens)

But this is not happening when buffer size is less.

Please any one help me understand the issue.

Comment: Hey Ram did you make any progress on the issue?